# Angular 13: alinear a la izquierda un texto de un grid-tile

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angularjs

Muy buenas tardes, quisiera saber si es posible poder alinear el texto de un grid-tile a la izquierda, he estado investigando en varios foros y no he podido encontrar una solución.

Este es el código html de mi grid-tile:

```
<table>
  <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="35px">
     <mat-grid-tile>485038</mat-grid-tile>
     <mat-grid-tile>849830</mat-grid-tile>
 </mat-grid-list>
</table>
```

En las vistas, el grid se visualiza así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He aplicado distintos estilos al grid y ninguno le hace efecto al texto de adentro. Por lo que se, el propio angular alinea el texto del grid-tile al centro por defecto. quisiera saber como poder alinear el texto a la izquierda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para alinearlas a la izquierda de manera general en tu aplicación puedes añadir el siguiente código en tu archivo de estilos globales (normalmente llamado styles.css)

```
.mat-grid-tile .mat-grid-tile-content {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

---

Si lo que buscas el alinear algunas celdas particulares puedes conseguirlo modificando el código el código de la siguiente manera:

```
// añadimos una clase seguida del tile. En este caso la he llamado content-left
.mat-grid-tile.content-left .mat-grid-tile-content { 
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Y a continuación en aquellas tiles que quieras alinear a la izquierda añades la clase `content-left`.

```
<mat-grid-tile class="content-left">485038</mat-grid-tile>
```

un saludo

Comment: @Cris223511 En este [proyecto de stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k3fxj5?file=src%2Fstyles.scss) puedes verlo.

Comment: genial, ahora me quedó más claro y me funcionó, resulta que estaba entrando mal a la clase, muchas gracias.